# JPA query timeout

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Open JPA 2.0 - IBM implementation on WebSphere V8. I need to set query timeout at individual query level. How this can be achieved?

Using below hint will set timeout for all queries, but I need to control this for specific queries

> javax.persistence.query.timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errm, perhaps ...

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", timeout);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I set this property at persistence.xml level and also at code level, what will take precedence? Will the code level hint query.setHint override persistence.xml level configuration?

Comment: EMF level applies to all and is overridden by any locally set value.