# Tomcat Request cancelled by timeout

Tags: java, tomcat, request, timeout

I have a web application and I have problem with request timeout.  Problem is in request timeout. When I start my application locally my method needs more than 30 seconds to finish its job. Because of this after 30 seconds request will be cancelled. I haven't this problem in real server. It real server this request needs 3 seconds. I tried to increase connection timeout in server.xml in tomcat conf folder in this fragment `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>` , but this didn't solve my problem

Comment: so your job at server start up takes more than 30 seconds and tomcat is shutting down because your job is pending for too long ?

Comment: are you facing this issue in some IDE or standalone tomcat instance?

Comment: @Arkantos there is not problem in server starting. I start server without any problem, but when I called one concrete method it needed more than 30 seconds and after 30 seconds this request cancelled

Comment: @Mahendra Yes, I faced this problem in eclipse

Comment: is it a db request that is taking more than 30 secs or some web service request ?

Comment: This request gets data from db, but I faced this problem only on local machine, on real server this methods needs 3 seconds

Comment: If it's a simple `statement` that you're executing using JDBC, then you can set timeout on statement object itself before firing query like `java.sql.Statement.setQueryTimeout(40)` as 40 seconds

Comment: I am using JPA, so can I make same for query ?

Comment: Which provider are using for JPA ? Hibernate or something else ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011829/jpa-query-timeout) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244621/set-timeout-on-entitymanager-query)

Answer (score 0):

To increase Tomcat server timeout in Eclipse, go to server view tab then timeouts.
There specify start and stop timeout limits, applicable if your server is not starting.

If server is running fine and specific request is taking more time, then check your method, if some DB or webservice operation is taking more than expected time, which might be the cause of delay and ultimately request timeout.

Comment: @Mahenda the method needs more than 30 seconds on local machine, but on real server it needs 3 seconds, so problem is not in method's logic

Comment: if you can tell us what exactly you are doing in that Method, it will be better to understand.

Comment: I only making search request (select). Today method worked locally, it needed less than 30 seconds. Can it be problem with logs ? If there is too many logs

Comment: Yes, excessive logging may also be issue, it write logs to FileSystem. is logging level same on local and Production server.